# Migrated from camel version 4.0.0-M1 TO 4.0.0 - getting ERROR! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/spi/PluginManager

Tags: apache-camel, spring-boot-maven-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG9Z3.png)ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spi.PluginManager - Migrated from Apache camel version 4.0.0-M1 to 4.0.0 LTS.
error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/spi/PluginManager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmsI2.png)

pom.xml -
`<properties> <camel.version>4.0.0</camel.version> </properties>  <dependencyManagement> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId> <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-bom</artifactId> <version>${camel.version}</version> <type>pom</type> <scope>import</scope> </dependency> </dependencies> </dependencyManagement> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId> <artifactId>camel-opentracing-starter</artifactId> <version>3.20.2</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId> <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId> </dependency>`

I have tried to import this dependency -  org/apache/camel/spi/PluginManager
I am looking for this pluginManager class under spi package which has been removed from apache camel 4.0.0 LTS(I guess).

Comment: You are mixing Camel versions 3.20.2 (see camel-opentracing-starter) and 4.0.0. Make sure you use a single version for all dependencies.

Comment: @JamesNetherton - Your answer is correct - I removed camel-opentracing-starter dependency and only left with camel version 4.0.0 - It is working for me.Thanks.